# How to dismiss AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: android, memory, dialog, alert, dismiss

In the following code below, how do I dismiss the alert box? I don't want to cause a memory leak. I tried the .dismiss() on alertDialog, but that didn't work...
Thanks

```
// User pressed the stop button
public void StopMsg_button_action(View view){
    final EditText password_input = new EditText(this); // create an text input field
    password_input.setHint("Enter Password"); // put a hint in it
    password_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD); // change it to password type

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new Builder(this); // create an alert box
    alertDialog.setTitle("Enter Password"); // set the title
    alertDialog.setView(password_input);  // insert the password text field in the alert box
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // define the 'OK' button
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             String entered_password = password_input.getText().toString();
             if (entered_password.equals(my_password)) {
                locManager.removeUpdates(locListener); // stop listening for GPS coordinates
                startActivity(new Intent(Emergency_1Activity.this,Main_MenuActivity.class)); // go to main menu
             } else {
                 alert("Incorrect Password");
             }
        } 
    });
    alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // define the 'Cancel' button
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        } 
    });
    alertDialog.show(); // show the alert box
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

What didn't work about dismiss()?

You should be able to use either [Dialog.dismiss()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss%28%29), or [Dialog.cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#cancel%28%29)

```
alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // define the 'Cancel' button
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //Either of the following two lines should work.
        dialog.cancel();
        //dialog.dismiss();
    } 
});
```

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder` doesn't have `cancel` method

Comment: @xmenW.K. The `cancel()` is a method of the Dialog itself, not the builder.

Comment: Yes but in your code(& Question too) `alertDialog` is a `Builder`. Inside `onClick` you should have used `dialog` from param.

Comment: Great solution! Dump question.

Answer (score 50):

With the following code you can show a ListBox AlertDialog and when you press on a item you dismiss the Dialog. The order of code is importan.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

String names[] ={"A","B","C","D"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View convertView = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
alertDialog.setView(convertView);
alertDialog.setTitle("List");
final AlertDialog ad = alertDialog.show();

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(mContext, position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ad.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks alot!

Comment: Thank you!
The key here is to dismiss the dialog created with alertDialog.show(). Creating a dialog from the builder and calling dismiss on that dialog does not dismiss the same dialog we create when we call show(). This one had me stumped for a bit =)

Answer (score 36):

The code is very simple:

```
final AlertDialog show = alertDialog.show();
```

finally in the action of button for example:

```
show.dismiss();
```

For example with a custom alertdialog:

[image]

Code on java, you could create a Object AlertDialog:

```
public class ViewAlertRating {

    Context context;
    public ViewAlertRating(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void showAlert(){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        View alertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_test, null);
        alertDialog.setView(alertView);

        final AlertDialog show = alertDialog.show();

        Button alertButton = (Button) alertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
        alertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                show.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Code XML layout_test.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Valoración"
        android:id="@+id/text_test1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#ff37dabb"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/edit_test"
            android:hint="Descripción"
            android:textColor="#aa000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="#aa72777a"
            android:gravity="top" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="1.00"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enviar"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_test"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_selector" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

finally, call on Activity:

```
ViewAlertRating alertRating = new ViewAlertRating(this);
alertRating.showAlert();
```

Comment: great solution. Helped me a lot!

Comment: something which i was looking for :-)

Answer (score 20):

You must use this way if you don't want to put any buttons and have custom layout in which you have say textview and you want to dismiss alert dialog upon clicking of that textview:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.show();
```

then check

```
if(alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()){
      alertDialog.dismiss();
}
```

This is also true if you want to dismiss it somewhere else in your activity after checking some condition.

Comment: perfect and best answer with great explanation

Comment: Yep, this is the way. Why they didn't include a close method in the Builder itself beats me... Not everyone wants to use the default button. For custom AlertDialog this is the only way for now. Thank you

Answer (score 14):

This method demos the code that's needed .. from Namrata's earlier answer

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
private static void showDialog(Activity activity, int layoutId)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setView(dialoglayout);

    CustomDialog.doCustomLogic(activity, layoutId, dialoglayout);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.show();

    // caller assumes there will be a btn_close element present
    Button closeNowBtn = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
    closeNowBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just override create method and save the dialog instance. Then you can call dismiss

```
@Override
public AlertDialog create() {
    this.dialog = super.create();
    return this.dialog;
}
```

Somewhere at the code:

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: This the only solution that works for me. I created a class that extends from AlertDialog.Builder. With that,I could create my own dismiss method.

Answer (score 4):

To dismiss or cancel `AlertDialog.Builder`

```
dialog.setNegativeButton("إلغاء", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        dialogInterface.dismiss()
    }
});
```

You have to call `dismiss()` on the dialog interface.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and worked!

```
.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
               alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete example:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout,null);
    TextView tvcancel = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvcancel);
    TextView tvdisconnect = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvdisconnect);
    builder.setView(view);
    final AlertDialog ad = builder.show();

    tvdisconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ad.dismiss();
            stopVpn();
        }
    });

    tvcancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ad.dismiss();
        }
    });
```