# AlertDialog.Builder and dismiss method confusion

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

**The Current Scenario**

I have a gridView in my app and every cell is a custom layout of an image and a text.

When the user touches any cell it opens a dialogue via following code

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(layout);
        builder.show();
```

Now the object layout in `builder.setView(layout)` has the layout of a imageView , a text box and a button and is set via following code

```
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buy_set_quantity, null);
```

Now when the user fills the text box and presses the button I want the alert dialogue to "go away" but I can't find a way to do this.

**What have I tried**

i tried using `builder.dismiss()` but there is no method dismiss for `AlertDialog.Builder` type object and the following aswell

```
cancel();

hide();

remove();

finish();
```

This question has been asked many times on stack overflow and every one says to use `dismiss();` and no answer has been accepted or if there is then how?

How do you dismiss the `AlertDialogue.Bulder()`

**What works?**

Pressing the back button (from the three buttons at the bottom of screen in every android) works and the dialogue box is dismissed. But that is not how it should be. So I called the method `onBackPressed();` but that not only dismisses the dialogue but also takes the user to the previous activity.

Now does anybody know any new or different method that actually works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dismiss AlertDialog.Builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285235/how-to-dismiss-alertdialog-builder)

Comment: I already saw that and have mentioned in the post that AlertDialogue.bulder doesn't have these methods and it is written in that post aswell by OP. take a look again

Answer (score 2):

You should call `create()` to get the Dialog, then dismiss the Dialog.  For example:

```
final Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setView(layout)
        .create();
dialog.show();

// later, when you need to dismiss the dialog
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: its not Dialogue class its AlertDialogue.Builder and it has no method names dismiss();

Comment: I made your code work. change setView to setContentView(); get rid of create and it works fine. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

You can create an external boolean variable and override onBackPressed()

```
boolean isOpen = false;
void showDialogBuilder()
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(layout);
    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
           isOpen = false;
       }
    });
    isOpen = true;
    builder.show();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(isOpen)
    {
        isOpen = false;
        return;
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```